# Delay function until jQuery .load is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a site using ajax to load the main content, and I am using the following code to run a function (`afterLoad`) after the `.load()` is complete..

```
jQuery('.main-menu a').click(function(evt){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var elementClassName = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        History.pushState({}, '', href);

        jQuery('.content').load(href+ ' #main',afterLoad);
            function afterLoad() { 
                jQuery('.content').fadeIn(750);
                if (document.location.pathname == "/works/") {
                    jQuery(function($){ window.dzsp_init("#port0",{
                        settings_slideshowTime:3
                        ,settings_mode: "masonry"
                        ,title: ""
                        ,design_item_width: ""
                        ,design_item_height: ""
                        ,design_categories_style: "normal"
                        ,design_categories_pos: "top"
                        ,design_pageContent_pos: "top"
                        ,settings_disableCats: "off"
                        ,settings_lightboxlibrary: "zoombox"
                        ,settings_preloadall: "off"
                        ,audioplayer_swflocation: "http://sbmdesigns.net/wp-content/plugins/dzs-portfolio/ap.swf"
                        ,videoplayer_swflocation: "http://sbmdesigns.net/wp-content/plugins/dzs-portfolio/preview.swf"
                        ,disable_itemmeta: "off"
                        ,settings_ajax_loadmoremethod: "button"
                        ,settings_mode_masonry_layout: "masonry"
                        ,design_total_height_full: "off"
                        ,settings_mode_masonry_layout_straightacross_setitemsoncenter: "off"
                        ,design_item_height_same_as_width : "off"})
                    });
                }
            }
         return false;
    });
```

Everything works fine but on occasion `afterLoad` runs before `.load()` is complete. Is there anyway to delay `afterLoad` to ensure everything is finished loading before it fires.

Comment: any luck solving this?

Comment: I ended up placing the function in an external file and calling .getscript in the call back

Answer (score 0):

call the php function from jquery at the end of the script

something like

```
$.ajax({ url: 'script.php?argument=value&foo=bar' });
```

or

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.php');
```

and in your function do a check to see if the argument is present, if so proceed else skip